# is there a DIGITAL LITERACY

Tags: 13.04

I am in Africa, and I wish to know if there's any project that introduces new users to Ubuntu? Something like  [this project of MS on Digital literacy](http://www.microsoft.com/about/corporatecitizenship/citizenship/giving/programs/up/digitalliteracy/default.mspx).

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80799/a-linux-distro-project-for-digital-literacy

Answer (score 2):

In Cameroon there is the [iSchool](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CameroonianTeam/Projects/iSchool) project and the [Classroom](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CameroonianTeam/Projects/Classroom) project (on IRC), both of which are projects of the [Ubuntu Users in Cameroon Team](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CameroonianTeam). Information about other educational projects of the Ubuntu Users in Cameroon Team can be found on the [Ubuntu Cameroonian Team Projects wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CameroonianTeam/Projects).